# Redux Toolkit history API push

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

In some react/redux applications a transition to a route after some action has been dispatched must occur. In my case, I have exactly this situation. let me show you one reducer of a state slice.

```
nextStep: (state, action) => {
  const { steps } = state;

  if (steps[state.currentTopNavStep][state.currentStep + 1]) {
    state.currentStep++;
  } else {
    state.currentTopNavStep++;
    state.currentStep = 0;
  }
  if (action.payload.history) {
    const nextStep = steps[state.currentTopNavStep][state.currentStep];
    const { gendersMatch, valuesExist } = nextStep;
    let realNextStep;

    if (
      (valuesExist && valuesExist(state, fbObject)) ||
      (gendersMatch && gendersMatch(state))
    ) {
      state.currentStep++;
      realNextStep = steps[state.currentTopNavStep][state.currentStep];
    } else {
      realNextStep = nextStep;
    }

    const newRoute = realNextStep.route;
    action.payload.history.push(newRoute.path);
  }
}
```

On the last line I want to push a new route into the history, which I get as a payload when this action is dispatched. I would like to move the logic inside of the reducer into a middleware. reduxToolkit provides createAsyncThunk function. I want to get something like this:

```
const nextStep = createAsyncThunk(
  'state/nextStep',
  async (history, thunkAPI) => {
    const { state } = thunkAPI.getState();
    const { steps } = state;

    if (steps[state.currentTopNavStep][state.currentStep + 1]) {
      state.currentStep++;
    } else {
      state.currentTopNavStep++;
      state.currentStep = 0;
    }
    if (history) {
      const nextStep = steps[state.currentTopNavStep][state.currentStep];
      const { gendersMatch, valuesExist } = nextStep;
      let realNextStep;

      if (
        (valuesExist && valuesExist(state, fbObject)) ||
        (gendersMatch && gendersMatch(state))
      ) {
        state.currentStep++;
        realNextStep = steps[state.currentTopNavStep][state.currentStep];
      } else {
        realNextStep = nextStep;
      }

      const newRoute = realNextStep.route;
      const res = await history.push(newRoute.path);
      return res; //this will be the action payload
    }
  }
);
```

And then use this inside extraReducers:

```
 extraReducers: {
    [nextStep.fullfilled]: (state, action) => {
       //Here I face the problem, how to handle it in the reducer
      return action.payload;
    },
  },
```

Can Anybody help me with this case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing is that a middleware must not change state.
You will really have to do these separately from each other:

- reducer changes state
- middleware does side effects

Also, `createAsyncThunk` is not the right tool here. The purpose of cAT is to have a thunk that dispatches a "pending" action and then a "fulfilled" or "rejected" action. You don't seem to have any use for these here at all.
You either need to write a normal thunk by hand that first dispatches an action, after that dispatch gets the new state and then does the side effect, or you're gonna have to write a middleware for that yourself (which is pretty simple, as well, the docs have examples on that).

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  I searched everywhere, since the toolkit is a new tool, there are very few cases and I couldn't find anything useful. Can you provide me the docs where the examples of the middlewares are, I couldn't find anything good. 

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-4-store#middleware

RTK is just an abstraction over plain redux, so only use it where it makes sense - `createAsyncThunk` does not invalidate "normal" thunks, and the whole redux documentation is also still valid ;)

Comment: I got everything what you suggested to do. However, there is a little problem. From the thunk I can't have access to the Router history, where I need to push a new route. 
I am suffering on this problem the entire day. 
Inside of a normal thunk I want to push the new url into the history, and then inside of the reducer just make changes to the state, but how do I receive the history itself.

Comment: You can just pass it as an argument to the thunk action creator

Comment: Everything worked for me, thank you very much!!